# Question Symmetric 2-Tensors on Vector Fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors, vector-fields

I have a question on a direct computation. How would one compute the following
$$ (dx \odot dy ) \left(\frac{1+uv+xy}{1+xy} \frac{\partial}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) $$
and$$ (dy \odot dv ) \left(\frac{1+uv+xy}{1+xy} \frac{\partial}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) $$

I know the general formula is $(\omega \odot \eta )(a,b)= \frac{1}{2}(\omega(a)\eta(b) + \omega(b)\eta(a))$, but I am not sure how to do it with the certain vector fields above.

Comment: the symbol $\otimes$ is  meant to the tensor product... for the symmetric is $\odot$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A differential one-form on a smooth manifold $M$ is a $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear map $TM \to C^{\infty}(M)$. So, if $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M)$, $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, and $V$ is a smooth vector field on $M$,

$$\alpha(fV) = f\alpha(V).$$

Furthermore, in coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$, the vector fields $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ form a basis, and the one-forms $dx^j$ are the dual basis, so

$$dx^j\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right) = \delta_i^j =\begin{cases} 1 & i = j\\ 0 & i \neq j.\end{cases}$$

Comment: What happens to the coefficients of the vector fields? Do I apply $d$ to it too?

Comment: What type of objects are the coefficients of the vector fields?

Comment: Smooth functions, where (u,v,x,y) are local coordinates.

Comment: OK, so using the formula in your answer, you can reduce the task to evaluating one-forms on vector fields. The first part of my hint tells you what to do with the functions.

Comment: @Alvey: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks!